# Yield return deferred iteration problems

Tags: c#, recursion, iterator, yield-return

I know that yield return takes advantage of lazy loading but I'm wondering if I might be misusing the iterator or quite possibly need a refactor.

My recursive iterator method returns all the ancestors of a given `PageNode` including the `pageNode` itself.

```
public class PageNodeIterator {
    //properties and constructor left out for brevity

    public IEnumerable<IPageNode> ancestorsOf(IPageNode pageNode) {
        if(pageNode == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(("pageNode"));

        if (pageNode.url != pageNodeService.rootUrl) {
            yield return pageNode;
            if (pageNode.parent != null)
                foreach (var node in ancestorsOf(pageNode.parent))
                    yield return node;
        }
    }
}
```

In my call to `ancestorsOf`, I'm calling the method and then reversing the order of the returned `IEnumerable`, but since loading is deferred the call doesn't actually happen until I call `ToArray()` on the next line and at that point `pageNodeService` in my iterator method is null and a null reference exception is thrown.

```
ancestors = pageNodeIterator.ancestorsOf(currentNode).Reverse();
return ancestors.ToArray()[1].parent.children;
```

So, I'm wondering where I've gone wrong. What would be the proper way to use an iterator in this case, if at all?

I'm also wondering why `pageNodeService` is null at the time of execution. Even the execution is deferred shouldn't it still hold a value?

Comment: Beware (very much) the recursive IEnumerable with yield. It has very surprising and undesirable memory characteristics. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/03/23/all-about-iterators.aspx Consider maintaining your own stack/queue: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/08/01/recursion-part-two-unrolling-a-recursive-function-with-an-explicit-stack.aspx

Comment: What in the world happens when you have 2 yield returns in a function??

Comment: No problem with 2+ yield returns. State machine will make a stop on more places.

Comment: _at that point pageNodeService in my iterator method is null_ - Why? That shouldn't happen.

Comment: Crazy. I didn't know that was possible. Seems way more confusing than necessary.

Comment: @bflemi3: does you method works correctly when you remove iterator stuff ? First make sure you have the algorithm correctly done. Maybe write some unit tests. Then add iterator support. Your code will stay almost the same.

Comment: @PetarRepac Haven't tried that yet, but I have other recursive methods that are working just fine. I'm almost positive it has to with deferred loading from `yield return`, just don't know why.

Comment: X is an ancestor of X ?

Comment: @PetarRepac in the case of this method, the requirement was to return all ancestors including the starting pageNode. Perhaps the naming is a little misleading.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I agree, but I don't have a good enough understanding of the .net framework to be able to answer that. It seems fishy though - I'll look into that.

Comment: i think maybe its with .children,i guess children are also pagenodes.

Comment: Where does `pageNodeService` come from? How do you set it? Do you ever reset it to `null`? Ideally, could you include a short, but complete code that demonstrates this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really an answer... more of a suggestion for an alternative implementation that eliminates recursion. Too long to post as a comment.

```
    public IEnumerable<IPageNode> ancestorsOf(IPageNode pageNode) {
        if(pageNode == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(("pageNode"));
        Stack<IPageNode> stack = new Stack<IPageNode>();
        stack.Push(pageNode);
        while(stack.Any())
        {
            IPageNode n=stack.Pop();
            if (n.url != pageNodeService.rootUrl) {
                yield return n;
                if(n.parent != null)
                {
                    stack.Push(n.parent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thinking about it, you could remove the Stack altogether:

```
public IEnumerable<IPageNode> ancestorsOf(IPageNode pageNode) {
    if(pageNode == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(("pageNode"));
    IPageNode n = pageNode;
    while(n != null && n.url != pageNodeService.rootUrl)
    {
        yield return n;
        n = n.parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2004/10/29/249858.aspx) is some further reading on why this change is rather important; performance really suffers in recursive iterator blocks; more so than regular recursive functions.

Comment: Yes, that's a better explanation that I offered in my comments above.

Comment: I don't see how this traverses up through all the parents of the given `pageNode` though?

Comment: @bflemi3: because the parent goes on the stack and is retrieved from the stack on the next iteration of the loop. I had a think about what you're actually doing, and realise that no stack or recursion is really necessary. Take a look at the second code sample and let me know if this still fulfils your intent.

Comment: This really all boiled down to `pageNodeService` having a `protected set` on it. So when I used `Activator` to create the instance it wasn't able to set that property so it was null. I did however refactor my method with your second solution, so I'm going to give you the answer. Thanks again spender.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know where your bug is, and StackOverflow is not a service for debugging your code; I would solve your problem by running it in the debugger and looking for the bug.

However I will take this opportunity to point out that this:

```
public IEnumerable<IPageNode> AncestorsOf(IPageNode pageNode) {
    if(pageNode == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(("pageNode"));
    // Do stuff that yields
```

is slightly problematic because none of the code in the block runs until `MoveNext` is called for the first time.  In other words, if you do:

```
var seq = AncestorsOf(null); // Not thrown here!
using (var enumtor = seq.GetEnumerator())
{
    bool more = enumtor.MoveNext(); // Exception is thrown here!
```

which is very surprising to people. Instead write your code like this:

```
public IEnumerable<IPageNode> AncestorsOf(IPageNode pageNode) {
    if(pageNode == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(("pageNode"));
    return AncestorsOfIterator(pageNode);
}
private IEnumerable<IPageNode> AncestorsOfIterator(IPageNode pageNode)
{
    Debug.Assert(pageNode != null);
    // Do stuff that yields 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does it even make sense to use yield in this place - since by calling Reverse, [all the stuff must be buffered anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051612/how-does-ienumerablet-reverse-work) so you could instead just return the complete list of ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

Add starting node outside this iterator if you need it.

```
public class PageNodeIterator {
    //properties and constructor left out for brevity

    public IEnumerable<IPageNode> ancestorsOf(IPageNode pageNode) {
        if(pageNode == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(("pageNode"));

        if (pageNode.url != pageNodeService.rootUrl)
        {
            if (pageNode.parent != null ) 
            {
                yield return pageNode.parent;
                yield return ancestorsOf(pageNode.parent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The ancestor iteration should continue until `pageNode.url != pageNodeService.rootUrl`. That logic isn't contained in your method.

Comment: Updated, but then the method should have some other name, because we are nor returning just ancestors, there are other requirements. Maybe better to put these additional requirement outside iterator ?

Comment: I agree, I'll look into refactoring that. Thanks Petar :)